# How do i copy members of a struct into an array of double in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, copy

I have a struct of a struct having members like this

```
typedef struct{
    double xMin;
    double yMin;
    double zMin;
    double xMax;
    double yMax;
    double zMax;
    double xMedian;
    double yMedian;
    double zMedian;
    double xMean;
    double yMean;
    double zMean;
    double xVar;
    double yVar;
    double zVar;
    double xStD;
    double yStD;
    double zStD;
}featureSet_t;

typedef struct{
    featureSet_t acc_features;
    featureSet_t gyr_features;
    featureSet_t mag_features;
}combinedFeatureSet_t; 

combinedFeatureSet_t featureSetOfPolledData;
double copy[54] = {0};
```

now i want to copy the members of the above instance into the array of double say, for eg.,

```
copy[0] =  featureSetOfPolledData.acc_features.xMin;
..
..
copy[53] =  featureSetOfPolledData.mag_features.zstD;
```

Its too tedious.
Pls help whats the best way to do this.

Comment: If you want to do it in a portable way, then you will have to work hard and copy element-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to simply use memcpy. You'll need to guard against padding in the struct - there should be none in this case, but it is good practice to always do a compile-time check:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(featureSetOfPolledData) == sizeof(double[54]), 
               "Unexpected padding detected.");
```

Once that's checked, then just merrily memcpy away:

```
memcpy(copy, &featureSetOfPolledData, sizeof(double[54]));
```

If you for some reason need to index individual item names, and changing the types is an option, consider using unions:

```
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    double xMin;
    double yMin;
    double zMin;
    double xMax;
    double yMax;
    double zMax;
    double xMedian;
    double yMedian;
    double zMedian;
    double xMean;
    double yMean;
    double zMean;
    double xVar;
    double yVar;
    double zVar;
    double xStD;
    double yStD;
    double zStD;
  };
  double array [18];
}featureSet_t;

typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    featureSet_t acc_features;
    featureSet_t gyr_features;
    featureSet_t mag_features;
  };
  double array [18*3];  
}combinedFeatureSet_t;
```

Now it would be possible to do stuff like:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<54; i++)
{
  copy[i] = featureSetOfPolledData.array[i];
}
```

but also to access individual items by name:

```
featureSetOfPolledData.acc_features.xMin = 1.0;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the quick answer. But what if  the double array copy[54] is declared in main.c?  and If am using the struct members in another .c file? sorry I am just a beginner. I am trying out the memcpy thing first btw.

Comment: @NikhileshKaranam You could put the typedefs in a "featureset.h" or such, then include that one from all .c files using those types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just memcpy served the purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Lundin provided a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971433/6699433)

This answer is not a solution. It's more of a warning of something common that you should not do. It can be tempting do do something like this, but you shouldn't.

```
double *ptr = &featureSetOfPolledData;
for(int i=0; i<53; i++) copy[i] = ptr[i];
```

This is likely to work, but does invoke undefined behavior.

So why does this cause undefined behavior? It's not completely obvious. The members in the struct is guaranteed to be in the same order as you wrote them. Padding can occur in a struct, but for doubles it is extremely unlikely that any compiler would use padding.

To be honest, I don't remember the details, but it has to do with that accessing the fields via a pointer this way just simply is undefined behavior in the C standard, and ANY undefined behavior may break your code. Especially if you are enabling optimization.

Lundin (same great guy again) wrote this in the comments below:

> It is UB because the struct layout isn't guaranteed to hold the same alignment as the double (it will in this case, in practice), but also because featureSetOfPolledData is not an array. The part of the standard is the additive operators C17 6.5.6 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." And then you go beyond your 1 element large array. The compiler is allowed to assume that you didn't access the data.
>
> C17 6.3.2.3 gives a special exception that allows you to dissect larger types by using character types. So just for the record, you can actually do like this well-defined by using a character type, increase it with sizeof(double) at each iteration, then convert to double. Like
>
> `for(uint8_t* ptr = &featureSetOfPolledData; 
>      ptr < (uint8_t*)&featureSetOfPolledData + sizeof(double[54]); 
>      ptr += sizeof(double)) { 
>           double d = *(double*)ptr; 
>           /* Put the copying code here */
>   }`
>
> Complete madness, but well-defined

Comment: It is UB because the struct layout isn't guaranteed to hold the same alignment as the `double` (it _will_ in this case, in practice), but also because `featureSetOfPolledData` is not an array. The part of the standard is the additive operators C17 6.5.6 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
type of the object as its element type."  And then you go beyond your 1 element large array. The compiler is allowed to assume that you didn't access the data.

Comment: C17 6.3.2.3 gives a special exception that allows you to dissect larger types by using character types. So just for the record, you can actually do like this well-defined by using a character type, increase it with `sizeof(double)` at each iteration, then convert to `double`. Like `for(uint8_t* ptr = &featureSetOfPolledData; ptr < (uint8_t*)&featureSetOfPolledData - sizeof(double[54]); ptr += sizeof(double)) { double d = *(double*)ptr; ... }` Complete madness, but well-defined.

Comment: Anyway, instead of demonstrating how it shouldn't be done because of UB, show how it should be done :)

Comment: @Lundin I think you have already shown how to do it in your answer. I have nothing to add to that. :)

Comment: I'll edit my answer later with the help of your comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning structure members to your array individually, as you describe, is the only strictly conforming way to do the job.  Any other alternative requires making assumptions about the layout of the struct members, and C does not make strong enough guarantees about that to support what you want.

However, if you are willing to assume that `featureSet_t` is laid out without any padding between members, or if you can use an implementation extension to ensure that, and if you want your array to be populated in structure member order, one structure's members after the other's, then you can use `memcpy()` to do this:

```
double copy[54];

memcpy(copy,      &featureSetOfPolledData.acc_features, 18 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(copy + 18, &featureSetOfPolledData.gyr_features, 18 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(copy + 36, &featureSetOfPolledData.mag_features, 18 * sizeof(double));
```

That achieves pretty good code simplicity in exchange for non-trivial assumptions about structure layout that nevertheless *probably* hold in practice.  You might, conceivably, get away with just one `memcpy()` of the overall `featureSetOfPolledData` object, but IMO, the minimal additional code simplification achieved that way does not justify the stronger assumptions about layout.

Comment: This is partially wrong. You DO have guarantees of the layout in a struct. If you have a particular compiler in mind, it SHOULD document the layout. It can differ from compiler to compiler though.

Comment: @Broman, "C does not make strong enough guarantees" says nothing about what a given implementation may promise.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing that might work as far as sticking to the standard would be to create a `union` of the struct and the array and to validate that they are the same size:

```
static_assert(sizeof(combinedFeatureSet_t) == sizeof(double [54]), "size mismatch");

typedef union {
    combinedFeatureSet_t featureset_struct;
    double featureset_list[54];
} featureset_u;

featureset_u u;
u.featureset_struct = featureSetOfPolledData;
// read u.featureset_list
```

The `static_assert` verifies that the struct has no internal padding.  With that, the array members overlay exactly the struct members and they have the same type.

With this union, you can freely read from the array and write to the struct or vice versa.

Comment: #fastestguninthewest  Pretty much identical to my answer, but I'll up-vote you still :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a function taking a `combinedFeatureSet_t` and returning a `double array`. It calls another function returning a `double array` from your `featureSet_t` for each `featureSet_t`. 
From there, you'll only have to call the first function to get your `array`.